# Sending Mails from Oulook to Other accounts

Tags: c#, .net, email

How to send the email through mine company email id

Like every company use to give some email id to its associates like xyz@abc.com

How to send the mails through this id to other accounts. Also I don't have passwords for this id, then how to send the email in this situation.

Comment: I think that you shouldn't send emails with a sender address for which you do not have the password. Something appears wrong to me. In what situation would you need that? I wouldn't like it at all if it was easy to send emails with somebody else's email address as the sender. I know there are email servers that are open and allow you to do things like that. But I hope at the same time that those email servers are black listed and no email is forward from there. But maybe I got it all wrong and there is a legitimate reason for doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class. Other than the `from` and `to` addresses you will need your company's SMTP server:

```
var message = new MailMessage();
message.To.Add("to@abc.com");
message.Subject = "This is the Subject";
message.From = new MailAddress("from@abc.com");
message.Body = "body of the mail";
using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.abc.com"))
{
    smtpClient.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: 'you will need your company's SMTP server' - and probably a user id and password for that SMTP server

Comment: @Tim, the OP mentioned Outlook, so I assumed Exchange server which usually is configured using integrated windows authentication so in this case it won't be necessary but of course it's an assumption. Good point.